# Использование веб камеры в Java

Tags: java, web-camera

Что нужно, чтобы в Java создать программу для работы с веб-камерой? Приведите пример программы, которая при запуске сохраняет одну фотографию и закрывается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна или JMF, или FMJ (особой разницы нет: у них API сходный).

[Capture Video from Camera with Java JMF](http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/).

> This example program will capture the video and audio stream from a Logitech QuickCam Pro 3000 USB camera for 10 seconds and stores it on a file, named "testcam.avi".

Answer (score 0):

Такие вопросы не раз поднимались. Задача точно имеет решение (сколько-то лет назад видел такое).

[SO: Capturing image from webcam in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java)

[SO: What is the best method to capture images from a live video device for use by a Java-based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115835/what-is-the-best-method-to-capture-images-from-a-live-video-device-for-use-by-a-j)

Answer (score 0):

-JMF

-Video4Linux4Java project

-FMJ Project